# Setting up a Spring MVC Maven "Hello World" webapp in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to set up a spring webapp in Intellij. I am using Maven to manage dependencies and a local Tomcat webserver. So far I have created the project using the Spring MVC template.

I am basically following this tutorial, but with Intellij 13.1.6 and using the Spring MVC template:
http://alfasin.com/setting-up-spring-web-project-on-intellij-using-maven/

I would assume that this would allow me to get a "Hello World" app up and running quickly. However, I am getting 500 internal errors that I am having trouble solving.

When I try to run the app I usually get this error:
[image: Class Not Found]

Seemingly randomly, I will sometimes get this error instead:
[image: Unable to compile class]

This is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.maynard.pipes"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

This is my controller:

```
package com.maynard.pipes;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController 
{   
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
<artifactId>project-pipes</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>project-pipes</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>project-pipes</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my Tomcat configuration:
[image: tomcat]

If anyone can point out what I've gotten wrong I would appreciate it. I still have much to learn on the configuration side of development. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSP version you using is not compatible with the Tomcat 8 version.
Check this out: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by downgrading to from Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 7. I am not sure why this worked, but I can now see "Hello World".

Answer (score 0):

```
   package com.abc.controller;
   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public class HelloWorldController {
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("HelloWorldController"); 
       @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView helloController() {
      logger.info("inside Controller");
      String message = "Hello World";
      return new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage", "message", message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  

            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  

            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  

xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  

      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  

      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  

               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-        3.0.xsd"> 

           <context:component-scan  base-package="com.abc.controller" />  


  <bean  
                                                                                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <dependencies>  

        <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency> 
          <groupId>junit</groupId>  
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
            <version>3.8.1</version>  
             <scope>test</scope>  
             </dependency>  
               <dependency>  
                 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>  
                <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>  
               </dependency>  
              <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>  
           </dependency>  
                  <dependency>  
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
         <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>  
                   </dependency>  
                 <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>  
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>  
      </dependency>  
         <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
         <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>  
                   </dependency>  
                 <dependency>
         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
             <version>1.2.17</version>
             </dependency>
              </dependencies>
```

Comment: This dependecies you use it is enough to run hello world using spring mvc

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
       version="3.0">
         <display-name>Spring_Annotation</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                  </welcome-file-list>

           <servlet>
             <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
           <servlet-
      class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-
 class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet-config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
           </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
               </servlet-mapping>
                  </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         <html>
         <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-
              8859-1">
        <title>Index Page</title>
              </head>
         <body>
           <a href="hello.html">CLICH HERE</a>  
            </body>
             </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <html>
            <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-
                   8859-1">
                   <title>Success Page</title>
                         </head>
                    <body>
                <h2>${message}</h2>
                      </body>
                              </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This are the files on top which i posted i successfully deploy the application and printed Hello World if any one  facing any issue please go through this flow and generate war follow my pom.xml.if after that if you getting 404 error code than restart your eclipse once again it sure work.